# Find minimum sum from all possible split combinations in a matrix

Tags: r, grouping, combinations

If I have a matrix with the structure below:

```
    A  B  C  D  E  F
A   -  12 3  5  7  9
B   -  -  8  11 6  2
C   -  -  -  10  1  7 
D   -  -  -  -  17 1 
E   -  -  -  -  -  19
F   -  -  -  -  -  -
```

I would like to split the A-F into 2 groups and find the combination with the minimum sum.
(If the combination is [ACD, BEF], the sum will be (3+5+10)+(6+2+19)=45 .)

In the real dataset, there will be a 2700X2700 matrix and I would like to split them into 13 groups of 200 items and 1 group of 100 items (13x200+1x100 = 2700).
Is there a good way in either python or R code to handle this?

Thank you.

Update:

Thank you @jay.sf. The list of gene2 indeed answers my question with the mock dataset, but in the output somehow the gene1 list is always "DEF".

It is fine with me just ignoring the following line "attr(s, "group1") <- g1"

However, when it comes to multiple groups and large datasets (2700 rowsXcolumns into 100 groups), the comboGeneral() could not work. Currently, I am trying to use the comboGroups() instead, although there is no parameter "FUN" in its arguments.

Comment: It looks like the only way to get through this will be to check every ... single ... combination ("NP" problem?). Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: why dont you do one thing add each row in a list and then add add the rows in another list then you can find min in each row in the matrix and to the sum of it (with python)

Comment: Is this an exact cover problem? Like a sudoku, which can be solved using dancing links... also, do your groups need to be of equal size?

Comment: Please avoid multi-language tags unless issue involves both with APIs like `rpy2` or `reticulate`. Pick one, make an attempt, post *specific* errors/issues.

Comment: This is unclear to me, how do you get from [ACD, BEF], to (3+5+10)+(6+2+19)=45?

Comment: @jay.sf cells where both row and column are in the group, i.e. group ACD: rowA,colC + rowA,colD + rowC,colD `3 + 5 + 10`

Comment: For your purposes does it have to be the definitive absolute minimum partition, or would a heuristic finding a low total sum approximate solution be good enough?

Comment: @pseudospin When I tried to estimate the possible combination with 2700 into 20 groups with comboGroupsCount(2700, 20), the number is >>>2^31. Even  comboGroupsCount(20, 10) yields 654729075 combinations. Thus, the exhaustive approach might be difficult or takes forever to run.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `RcppAlgos::comboGeneral`, which is basically a C version of `combn` and should find columns combinations sufficiently fast.

The logic of following code is to find all combinations of three column names, subset them to group 1 and the negation to group 2 and `sum` both together and list the output. `attr` assigns the sum as attribute to the list elements.

```
stopifnot(all.equal(rownames(m), colnames(m)))
stopifnot(ncol(m) %% 2 == 0)

n <- colnames(m)

library(RcppAlgos)
r <- comboGeneral(n, length(n)/2, FUN=function(i) {
  l <- length(i)
  g1 <- i
  g2 <- n[!n %in% i]
  s <- sum(c(m[g1, g1], m[g2, g2]), na.rm=TRUE)
  attr(s, "group1") <- g1
  attr(s, "group2") <- g2
  return(s)
})
```

Now, we can get the sums from the attributes.

```
sums <- sapply(r, attr, "sum")
table(sums)
# 25 30 43 45 46 51 53 55 60 64 
#  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

Finally, to get the result we subset the `min`imums.

```
r[sums %in% min(sums)]
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$g1
# [1] "D" "E" "F"
# 
# [[1]]$g2
# [1] "B" "D" "F"
# 
# attr(,"sum")
# [1] 25
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$g1
# [1] "D" "E" "F"
# 
# [[2]]$g2
# [1] "A" "C" "E"
# 
# attr(,"sum")
# [1] 25
```

---

*Data:*

```
m <- structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
3L, 8L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 11L, 10L, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 6L, 1L, 
17L, NA, NA, 9L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 19L, NA), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 
    "F")))
```